# Slice-category-like terminology question

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology

Let $\mathcal C$ be a category, and consider a new category $\mathcal C'$ with

$Obj(\mathcal C') := \{$pairs $(X \in Obj(\mathcal C), T \in End_{\mathcal C}(X)) \}$

$Hom_{\mathcal C'}((X,T_X),(Y,T_Y)) := \{R \in Hom_{\mathcal C}(X,Y) : T_Y \circ R = R\circ T_X \}$

> Does this $\mathcal C'$ have a name, or any non-formally-obvious properties?

I suppose that the more natural construction would let $T$ be an arbitrary morphism instead of an endomorphism. In my context $\mathcal C$ is additive and I require also that $T^2=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you have defined is just called the **category of endomorphisms** in $\mathcal{C}$. See for instance Marian Mrozek's 1992 [paper](http://www2.im.uj.edu.pl/actamath/PDF/29-181-198.pdf) *Normal functors and retractors in categories of endomorphisms* for some properties of this category.

The oldest mention that I have found in the literature so far is

> **Almkvist, Gert**, *The Grothendieck ring of the category of endomorphisms*, J. of Algebra 28 (1974), 375–388.

Almkvist restricts attention to the case where $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of $A$-modules which admit a finite projective resolution. See also [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136195/how-does-it-end) of mine about homotopy properties of iterating the endomorphism construction.

Comment: Thanks for that Mrozek reference, Vidit.  I'm very glad to discover it, for reasons that are probably quite different to Allen's (http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/12/the_eventual_image_part_2.html).  Mrozek, like me, uses $\text{Endo}(\mathcal{C})$ for Allen's category.  Tiny nitpick: it's better to call it the category of endomorphisms *in* $\mathcal{C}$, not *of* $\mathcal{C}$, since the latter sounds like the category of endofunctors of $\mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 6):

$\mathcal{C}'$ is isomorphic to a functor category, namely the category of functors $\mathbb{B} \mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{C}$, where $\mathbb{B} \mathbb{N}$ is the category freely generated by an endomorphism, i.e. the category with one object $*$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(*, *) = \mathbb{N}$.

If $\mathcal{C}$ is an $\mathbf{Ab}$-category and you also require $T^2 = 0$, then $\mathcal{C}'$ is isomorphic to the category of additive functors $\mathbb{B} A \to \mathcal{C}$, where $\mathbb{B} A$ is the $\mathbf{Ab}$-category with just one object $*$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(*, *) = A$, where $A$ is the ring $\mathbb{Z} [T] / (T^2)$. As always, $\mathcal{C}'$ is an $\mathbf{Ab}$-category.

Comment: $C'$ can also be described as the subcategory of the category $\text{Arr}(C)$ of arrows in $C$ with the same source and target, or equivalently as the equalizer of the two projections $\text{Arr}(C) \to C$. This reflects the fact that $B\mathbb{N}$ itself can be described as the coequalizer of the two inclusions of the terminal category $\text{pt}$ into the interval category $I$. This is a categorical version of the construction of the circle by gluing together an interval at its endpoints, and so one can think of $C'$ as a categorical version of the (free) loop space.

Comment: $C'$ is not the full subcategory of $\mathrm{Arr}(C)$ on arrows with the same source and target. In that full subcategory, a morphism $(X, f:X \to X) \to (Y, g:Y \to Y)$ is a pair of morphisms $p,q : X \to Y$ such that $g \circ  p = q \circ f$, whereas in the actual endomorphism category the morphisms are just those where $p=q$, @QiaochuYuan. The equalizer description is correct, however (being an equalizer also forces $p=q$).

Answer (score 3):

I would call it the category of representations of the loop quiver in $C$.